# spring 3.0 aop Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting 'name pattern' error

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

**The following is my pointcut and advise declaration**

```
//PointCut on A method which takes two parameters and is in a DAO
@Pointcut("execution(backend.repository.QuestionsRepository.AnswerQuestion (..))")
public void answerQuestionPointCut() {}


@Around(
   value="web.activity.advisors.UserActivityAdvisor.answerQuestionPointCut()",
   argNames="question,answer"
)

 // Do something

}
```

I get the following error

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting 'name pattern' at character position 65
execution(backend.repository.QuestionsRepository.AnswerQuestion (..))
                                                                 ^
```

Am stuck on this, Any pointers

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are missing the return type:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* backend.repository.QuestionsRepository.AnswerQuestion (..))")
```

and you have to bind the argument names, something like this:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* backend.repository.QuestionsRepository.AnswerQuestion (..)) 
&& args(question, answer)") // wrapped for readability only
```

### Example Solution

**Service Interface:**

```
package foo.bar.service;
public interface Service{
    void whack(String thing, Integer thang);
}
```

**Implementation class:**

```
package foo.bar.service;
public class DefaultService implements Service{
    @Override
    public void whack(final String thing, final Integer thang){
        System.out.println(
            "Inside thing: " + thing + ", inside thang: " + thang
        );
    }
}
```

**Spring AOP aspect:**

```
@Aspect
public class ServiceAspect{

    @Pointcut("execution(* foo.bar.service.*.*(..))")
    public void serviceMethodExecution(){
    }

    @Around(value = "serviceMethodExecution() && args(param1, param2)")
    public void aroundServiceMethodExecution(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp,
        final String param1,
        final Integer param2) throws Throwable{

        System.out.println("Before thing: " + param1 + ", before thang: "
            + param2);
        pjp.proceed();
        System.out.println("After thing: " + param1 + ", after thang: "
            + param2);
    }

}
```

**Spring Context XML:**

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="false"  />
<bean class="foo.bar.service.DefaultService" />
<bean class="foo.bar.aspects.ServiceAspect" />
```

**Main class for testing:**

Now here's a main method to test the whole process. It starts a Spring ApplicationContext <s>without XML configuration</s> with the above XML defining the service bean and the aspect (it turns out that the solution without XML only worked because I had AspectJ weaving turned on, I don't know what beans I have to include to enable aspectj-autoproxy, so I now use `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` with this minimal XML):

```
public static void main(final String[] args){
    final ApplicationContext applicationContext =
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/aspectContext.xml");
    final Service service = applicationContext.getBean(Service.class);
    service.whack("abc", 123);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before thing: abc, before thang: 123
Inside thing: abc, inside thang: 123
After thing: abc, after thang: 123
```

This should get you started. Basically: you need to check that the methods you are intercepting are backed by a service interface if you use JDK proxies (spring default). Read here about [Spring AOP proxy mechanisms](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying).

**Note:**

As you see I bind the method arguments to the aspect, not the pointcut, hence making the pointcut reusable for methods with different argument signatures. But it would also be possible to bind them in the pointcut, like this:

```
@Pointcut(value = "execution(* foo.bar.service.*.*(..)) && args(a,b)",
          argNames = "a,b")
public void serviceMethodExecution(final String a, final Integer b){
}

@Around(value = "serviceMethodExecution(param1, param2)",
        argNames = "param1,param2")
public void aroundServiceMethodExecution(final String param1,
    final Integer param2,
    final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{

    System.out.println("Before thing: " + param1 + ", before thang: "
        + param2);
    pjp.proceed();
    System.out.println("After thing: " + param1 + ", after thang: "
        + param2);
}
```

Comment: Thnaks, I guess a) means this @Pointcut("execution(*backend.repository.QuestionsRepository.AnswerQuestion (..)) && args(question, answer)")
    public void answerQuestionPointCut(Question question,Answer answer) {}

Comment: I could not figure out what b means, need some more directions

Comment: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting 'name pattern' at character position 66
execution(*backend.repository.QuestionsRepository.AnswerQuestion (..)) && args(question, answer)

Comment: Thanks a ton .. got it working, was missing the return type and the other points you mentioned. the spring documentation is really confusing

Comment: *Thanks a ton .. got it working*. You're welcome. But the best way of saying thank you here is accepting the answer.

Comment: Hi @Sean Patrick Floyd. I have a problem similar to this one [here: Advise method error in Spring AOP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095481/advise-method-error-in-spring-aop/27095555#27095555). I'm stuck and was wondering whether you would mind taking a look and helping me out if you can? Thank you. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @user3663765 ask a separate question or contact me (see my profile page)

Comment: I published a separate question [Advise method error in Spring AOP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095481/advise-method-error-in-spring-aop/27095555#27095555)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd, I had same issue & code, and reading your answer, i passed arguments.
before:
@Pointcut("execution(* com.mani.*.*.*(..)))
 public void general() {
}
After:

@Pointcut(value = "execution(* com.mani.*.*.*(..)) && args(a,b)", argNames = "a,b")
public void generalPointcut(final String a, final String b) {
}
On running wth updtd code, i'm getting exception

Answer (score 3):

You should write like this

```
@Pointcut("execution(* backend.repository.QuestionsRepository.AnswerQuestion (..))")
```

pay attention to `"... (* backend..."`

`*` **and** a space should be used.

Comment: Please make an effort to read previous answers before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have similar behaviour with the `@Before` annotation in `org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before`.

You can use the expression without *execution* key word and without a return type:

```
@Before("allGetters()")
```

or with both:

```
@Before("execution(public * allGetters())")
```

but you can not use the `execution` keyword without using the return type.