# Advise method error in Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, javafx, spring-aop

I'm trying to run an advise in a Spring AOP program but I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:894)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: .......
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set .......
```

The problem I have is that I have prototype beans which I think (But I'm not certain) might be behind this error.

I have my Beans declared as annotations, except for the FXML file controllers which are injected via an AppFactory class:

a sample `Home.fxml` file controller bean gets injected like so:

```
@Configuration
public class AppFactory {

    @Bean
    public HomeController homeController() throws IOException {
        return (HomeController) loadController("/Home.fxml");
    }

    FXMLLoader loader = null;

    protected Object loadController(String url) throws IOException {
        loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(url));
        loader.load();
        return loader.getController();
    }
}
```

The ones declared by annotating a class look like, for example:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY_OBJECT")
public class EntityObject extends RevEntity {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

The Aspect class looks like:

```
@Aspect
public class SampleAopAspect {

    @Before("execution(public String getName())")
    public void timeUpdataedAdvice() {
        System.out.println("Before method ->");
    }
}
```

The FXML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean id="sampleAopAspect" class="org.SampleAopAspect" />

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="wakiliproject"/>

</beans>
```

How can I make the advice methods to run, or whare am I going wrong? Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prototype beans need to specify a proxyMode, e.g.:

```
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")
```

Barry

Comment: Thanks for the reply @blagerweij. Now I get the error `Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting ')' at character position`!

Comment: Your pointcut syntax in the question above is correct, so you must have changed something. If you want us to help you spot syntax errors, how about sharing the code with us?

Comment: You're using an inline pointcut in the SampleAopAspect, which should be fine. Are you sure that the provided snippets are copied correctly? For example, the 'EntityObject' class is both a 'Component' and an 'Entity' at the same time, which is very unusual.

BTW, if you're looking for a way to populate the last-modified username and timestamp, you may want to take a look at spring-data AuditorAware:

`<jpa:auditing auditor-aware-ref="auditorAware" />`
See [http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/]

Comment: Thanks @blagerweij. It worked great! I had a prototype `@Component` I had left without changing to `@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")`. Did what you advised. Now I'm good. Thanks a lot again>